# jquery - triggering a click event when an image gets focus

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` element to which I am dynamically generating an input field and an image besides it. When I click on the input field and then use the tab key, the image gets the focus.

**What I want to do**

When the image has the focus, I want to trigger an enter key event.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("div#myDiv").html("<input type='text' tabindex='1'></input><a><img src='icon.gif' tabindex='2'></img></a>");
});
```

Comment: Are you triggering a key event to call another handler? If so, why not put the handler code into a function and call it from both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just us the `focus` event on the image. I added a `focustrigger` class to the image so that this code does not apply to all `img` elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("div#myDiv").html("<input type='text' tabindex='1'></input><a><img src='icon.gif' class='focustrigger' tabindex='2'></img></a>");

     $('.focustrigger').focus(function() {
         // Trigger your "enter key event" here.
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your handle the enter key event like this:

```
$("#myDiv input").keypress( function(evt) {
    var code = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    if ( code == 13 ) alert( "OK" );
} );
```

You can use this to trigger it when the image gets the focus:

```
$("#myDiv img").focus( function( ) {
    var evt = jQuery.Event('keypress');
    evt.keyCode = 13;
    $("#myDiv input").trigger( evt );
} );
```

Comment: You can just use `evt.which`. jQuery makes it cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you'll need:

http://jsbin.com/upowip

There's an edit link in the upper right or just view source.

Comment: Actually in my example you can put whatever in the "on" function to handle whatever. You can handle the keypress event on the img and check for the enter key code.